# How do I disable iOS home screen "swipe-down search bar" gesture?

Tags: iphone, ios, spotlight

Basically if you use an iPhone or iPod touch, if you swipe down from your home screen, the home screen will fade, and a search bar appears on the top (for spotlight search, I guess). If Siri suggestion is on, you also see suggested apps there.

I would like to disable the feature completely, so that swiping down from home screen **does not** trigger any action.

**Reason:** I found it very often that when I swipe home screen pages left and right, it is detected as a down-swipe and triggers the search bar --
 especially often on a bigger screen like iPhone 6 and iPhone 6s. This is very annoying and disturbing. Also, it could be very laggish on an old device.

I did not see any related option in Settings. I could turn of Siri suggestions and spotlight search contents for each application, but there does not seem to be a way to disable this gesture action. Is there anything in Accessibility that could help?

Comment: i'm looking for an answer to this too. it's annoying me. also wish i could deactivate lock screen from appearing every time you switch the screen off.